# Tortoise SVN - Resolve Conflict, add both?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

A lot of times it happened, that multiple developers replaced the same line of code (one in branch, one in trunk for example), which resulted a conflict (when we did a branch->trunk merge). In these situations, the merge tool offers me to take either theirs, or mine. However, I want TortoiseSVN to take both, and put them under each other. Till now, what I was doing is that I accepted one, and manually copy-pasted the other one under it.

Is there a built-in solution for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Resolve Conflict dialogue, click on "Edit conflict" (instead of "Use local" or "Use repository"):

[image: Resolve Conflict dialogue]

If you are using the default tool (TortoiseMerge), right click on each conflict and select an appropriate option:

[image: TortoiseMerge]

Otherwise, go to "TortoiseSVN/ Settings" and set it back at "External Programs/ Merge Tool".

Comment: I can't believe how blind I am, for not noticing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a built-in solution for this situation?

Visual Merge tool (instead of internal merge), which will fire on conflict and allow you to edit merge-result manually, as you want